# Pragmatic Way to Override Equals for Classes With Many Fields

Tags: java

I have a class that contains a large number of data members - some of which are user defined classes of their own, Lists, HashMaps, etc...

Let's say there are 20 data members.

Is there a more pragmatic way to override the `equals()` operator other than checking for equality against every single field?

For example (using Guava):

```
HashMap<k,v> dataMember1;
String dataMember2;
CustomClass dataMember3;
etc...

@Override   
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Objects.deepEquals(this.dataMember1, obj.dataMember1) &&
    Objects.equals(this.dataMember2, obj.dataMember2) &&
    Objects.equals(this.dataMember3, obj.dataMember3) &&
    etc...
}
```

I've seen these large blocks in production code before, but they always seemed so redundant.

Comment: It may imply you have a design problem and the class is just too big, or that you shouldn't even be implementing `equals()` on that class.

Comment: Without a doubt. However, at this point, refactoring this specific class will take some serious work.

Comment: If the logic of your design demands that equality of objects be defined in terms of the equality of corresponding fields, then there's no shortcut. Perhaps revisit your design. Also, you might consider posting this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/; it seems more geared to that forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think how you're implementing the `equals` is fine, however it may be a code smell that you should pull some of those fields into their own classes.  Then you would be comparing fewer fields, as each class can implement its own `equals`.

Regardless, the problem is a symptom, not a cause.

Answer (score 2):

There is an annotation processor for Java called [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), which offers some nice annotations to deal with boilerplate code, including [@EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode).

In cases when immutability is acceptable/desirable, [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) and [Google AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) libraries provide annotations for creating value classes along with all the boilerplate code, including `equals()` method.

Comment: +1.  If you're unable to decrease the number of fields, Lombok can at least handle a lot of that logic for you.